# XBMC standalone on external harddrive

Tags: external-hard-drive, kodi

Is it possible for XBMC to run standalone on for example an external hard drive?

I have got two laptops at home and would like to access the same XBMC database with both of them, without having to switch to the laptop I have installed XBMC on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://portableapps.com/node/19745

XBMC was really designed to be cross platform (i.e. portable) so its pretty good about keeping all its settings in a local file already.

Comment: Ah.. The last comment on that page was very useful:

"XBMC is portable out of the box. It does not write anywhere outside it's own folder if started with the -p switch. This is even an option from the installer - you can install it wherever you like and it'll create the shortcut for you.

We (Team XBMC) welcome any improvements to the build system that allows this to be done in a better way. Please drop us a line at http://xbmc.org and let us know any improvements you need.

Cheers,
Jonathan (Team XBMC)"

Thanks. Will try it when I am at home.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MYSQL database synchronization plugin for XBMC or use Plex, which handles all of that for you.

With Plex, you run one server somewhere, anywhere, and you can login and access it from anywhere or locally.

You can add additional users that are also then able to access the same database from anywhere.

If you want control over who has access to what and where, you can do that.